# Configure sstable size in Scylla LCS compaction

Tags: scylla

I want to configure my scylla 2 node instance to LCS compaction. I did it with the query.

But the problem is it is creating `160mb` sstables which is the default value of sstables in LCS compaction. I want to change this is 1gb and am not able to understand how to put this into my `scylla.yaml` file.

I read their documentation which says adding `sstable_size_in_mb` field will change the size of the sstables but it is not working for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Did you alter the keyspace? It should work as defined in https://docs.scylladb.com/getting-started/compaction/
You may need to wait for more table creation or compactions

Comment: I added the field in the query and it started working. However, I want to know the field name to add the same in the config file.